# getting the error type of could not deserialize

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "report_queue")
public class Team implements Serializable {   @Id
    private Long id;
    private String queue;
    private Number offered;
   private Number answered;
    private Number answerRate;
    @Column(name="abandoned")
    private Number abandoned;
    private Number  unmanaged;
    private String avgAbandonTime;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date totalTalkTime;
    private  Number avgTalkTime;

 public Team() {
        String queue;
        Number offered;
        Number answered;
        Number answerRate;
        Number abandoned;
        Number unmanaged;
        String avgAbandonTime;
        Date totalTalkTime;
        Number avgTalkTime;
    }

    public Team(Long id, String queue, Number answered, Number offered, Number answerRate, Number abandoned, String avgAbandonTime, Date totalTalkTime, Number avgTalkTime, Number unmanaged) {
       this.id = id;
       this.queue = queue;
       this.answered = answered;
       this.offered = offered;
       this.answerRate = answerRate;
       this.abandoned = abandoned;
       this.avgAbandonTime = avgAbandonTime;
       this.totalTalkTime = totalTalkTime;
       this.avgTalkTime =  avgTalkTime;
       this.unmanaged=unmanaged;
   }
//getters and setters..
```

```
public interface TeamRepo extends JpaRepository<Team, Long>{

  @Query(value="select q.id, q.queue,q.offered,q.answered,q.answerRate,q.abandoned,q.unmanaged,q.totalTalkTime,q.avgTalkTime,q.avgAbandonTime from(SELECT id as \"id\", queue AS \"queue\", COUNT(DISTINCT uniqueid) AS \"offered\", SUM(queuecallercomplete) AS \"answered\", ROUND(SUM(queuecallercomplete)/COUNT(DISTINCT uniqueid)*100,1) AS \"answerRate\", SUM(queuecallerabandon) AS \"abandoned\", SUM(queuecallerexit) AS \"unmanaged\", SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallercompleteAt)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallerleaveAt)) AS \"totalTalkTime\", ROUND(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallercompleteAt)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallerleaveAt))) AS \"avgTalkTime\", ROUND(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallerAbandonAt)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallerjoinAt))) AS \"avgAbandonTime\" FROM report_queue  GROUP BY queue)q",nativeQuery = true)
   List<Team> getAll();

 // @Query(value="SELECT new tech.spring.data.jpa.native.query.dto.TeamDto(select * FROM report_queue  GROUP BY queue ",nativeQuery = true)
 // public List<Team> findAll();
 @Query(value="SELECT id as \"id\", queue AS \"queue\", COUNT(DISTINCT uniqueid) AS \"offered\", SUM(queuecallercomplete) AS \"answered\", ROUND(SUM(queuecallercomplete)/COUNT(DISTINCT uniqueid)*100,1) AS \"answerRate\", SUM(queuecallerabandon) AS \"abandoned\", SUM(queuecallerexit) AS \"unmanaged\", SUM(UNI X_TIMESTAMP(queuecallercompleteAt)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallerleaveAt)) AS \"totalTalkTime\", ROUND(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallercompleteAt)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallerleaveAt))) AS \"avgTalkTime\", ROUND(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallerAbandonAt)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(queuecallerjoinAt))) AS \"avgAbandonTime\" FROM report_queue where  GROUP BY queue",nativeQuery = true)
public List<Team> findTeam();

    void deleteTeamById(Long id);

    Optional<Team> findTeamById(Long id);

}
```

About this error

ERROR 87656 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause

java.io.EOFException: null

Comment: it will helpful if you can put more classes and the point where you are getting failure .  Since others can not reproduce the error as enough information is not present , it will be difficult for them to help you . Please share complete code .

Comment: i have been edited my question